# Influence of Temperature on Biochemical Reactions

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry, enzymes, dna-rna

**Short question**

How (quantitatively speaking) does temperature influences rate of decay of proteins? I am looking for some general number/function, the influence of temperature on an average protein.

**Long question**

For computer modeling purposes, I am looking for some referenced quantitative measurements of the effect(s) of temperature on the dynamic of biochemical reactions. In particular, my question is:

> How does temperature influences rate of protein decay?

I am looking for a function (eventually expressing the michaelis-menten constant as a function of the temperature) that I can plug in my algorithms to incorporate the influence of various temperatures on the process I want to simulate. The model under simulation is an eukaryote such as Saccharomyces telluris (a yeast) for example living at some common range of temperature [5-35 °C]. I am not thinking to any particular protein rather I am looking for some approximative effect of temperature on the decay rate on an "average protein". I welcome any kind of expression of how temperature influences the rate of decay. Some values using the [Erying equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eyring_equation), [Van't Hoff equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_%27t_Hoff_equation) or a [$Q10$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q10_(temperature_coefficient)) (measured in some reasonable range [5°C - 35°C]) for examples would also fit my needs. I would be very surprise that there is not enough literature on the subject in order to get some average impact of temperature on protein decay rate but as a biologist (and not a biochemist) I can't wrap my head around this problem and can't find any satisfying article. Thanks for your precious help!

*I am not looking for...*

I am NOT looking for a theoretical explanation of how temperature influences these reactions (I have basic understanding of the importance of the activation energy as displayed on a Maxwell-Boltzman distribution and of the michaelis-menten equation). I am just looking for some empirical observations of how temperature influences proteins decay rate. I am not looking for any accurate value but only for some estimation that I can plug into my algorithms.

**Update**

Reading the comments I realize that my question is too broad in the sense that there might have too much variance in how different proteins respond to temperature in order to draw in general tendency. If this is so, someone willing to answer may reduce the question to transcription factor, to [General Transcription Factor (GTF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_transcription_factor) or even to [TFIIA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcription_factor_II_A).

What about [this article](http://www.ploscompbiol.org/article/info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pcbi.1003689) for example? I am not really able to extract from it the info I am looking for but it might be in here.

Comment: This question is extremely broad if you want to go beyond general arguments about activation energy. If you want specific functions, data, then you have to pick a specific system and go find literature about it. There is no one magic formula.

Comment: @Greg thanks for your comment. I reduced my post to one question and described the organism and the protein I am interested in. Hope that makes this question easier to answer

Comment: >I am not thinking to any particular protein rather I am looking for some approximative effect of temperature on the decay rate on an "average protein". || I'm afraid you won't find any. It really depends on the protein in question. For example, some enzymes successfully works at 90+ celsium, while others break down at ~30 celsium. I suppose, this have to deal with folding of proteins: a folded protein is significantly more stable, than linear polypeptide chain, but the folding breaks down at highter temperatures.

Comment: Ok, so do you think I could ask the same question for the [General Transcription Factor (GTF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_transcription_factor)? If not I may even reduce my question to [TFIIA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcription_factor_II_A). What do you think? (I updated my post in reaction to your comments) Thanks

Comment: @Remi.b With such specific, but deeply specialized question you should go to scholar google com and search for something like 'activity decay of <protein>' or similar.

Comment: well... that's the point I can't find anything. I might be too ignorant in the relevant field in order to really judge whether an article is of interest to me based on its title, I don't know but I personally keep failing to find the answer I need. That's why I came here on ChemistryBeta to ask you guys for some help.

Comment: I don't think you're going to find any non-specialists able to help here. As @permeakra mentioned, my feeling about "decay" here is going to depend on denaturation - when does this protein unfold or mis-fold. That depends entirely on the protein. I'd e-mail other people who do research (esp. folding studies) on that protein.

Comment: What about [this article](http://www.ploscompbiol.org/article/info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pcbi.1003689). I don't know sufficiently about Gibbs free energy and stuff to understand it but the article might give this answer I am looking for. What do you guys think? Rethinking about my issue I realize that I probably missed two keywords in my article research: Degradation and stability curve.

Comment: @Remi.b As a rule of thumb I would say, that the protein is active at least up to temperature that kills the cell. Other than that your only hope is that someone made measures for your specific protein. As for the article, it describes empirical correlation of stabilities in homologous proteins i.e. 1)it requires statistics on homologous proteins to be of any use and 2) it may be used to predict, but not guarantee.

Comment: @permeakra Does your rule of thumb imply that the rate of degradation is zero under ~50°C and after ~50°C all proteins would suddenly be non-functional.

Comment: @Remi.b Nope, it means that the degradation rate is slow enough to natural protein synthesis to overcome it. Protein renewal rate is easier to find, even though it depends on specific protein, and it ranges from about a hour to first tens of days for rats, for example. Still a too broad range, but at least it is something. But it does imply, that *some* human proteins may become non-functional somewhere around 43-50 celsium.

Comment: @permeakra Thanks a lot for all your comments. In reaction to your last comment I asked [this question](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/16436/how-does-temperature-influences-the-rate-of-protein-turnover).

Comment: @permeakra imho, not even 'degradation' is sufficiently defined. Degradation could refer to (a) amide bonds being hydrolysed, the protein degrading, (b) biological protein degradation processes, usually ubiquitination followed by degradation, (c) denaturation due to change of environment, followed either by ubiquitination-degradation or unspecific degradation. Luckily, (a) can be disregarded at temperatures you mentioned/pH-values anywhere near to in vivo. If intracellular protein levels are kept constant, it's either a physicochemical decay rate equal to the renewal rate or a biochemical one.

Comment: This question might be better suited for [Bio.SE](http://biology.stackexchange.com/), since proteins don't compare well to dead-chemistry polymers.

Comment: Since this was already asked and answered on Bio, I am going to close this one.